# Every finitely generated module is the quotient of a finitely generated projective module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

Every finitely generated module is the quotient of a finitely generated projective module.

I already find a proof of this but it uses tensor functor and flat modules propositions so im looking for a simpler proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it is a quotient of a finitely generated free module. Suppose that $R$ is your ring, and that $M$ is your module. Choose a generating set $\{m_1,...,m_n\}$. Define a module map $\varphi:R^n\rightarrow M$ by $$(r_1,...,r_n)\mapsto r_1m_1+\ldots+r_nm_n.$$ This map is surjective. By the First Isomorphism Theorem, $M$ is isomorphic to the quotient of $R^n$ by the kernel.

Comment: Nice but in order to prove thar the quotient of R^n by the kernel is a projective module which equivalence of projective module should i use? :/

Comment: I think the key point is that $R^n$ is projective, not $M$. I thought you wanted to prove that $M$ was isomorphic to a quotient of a finitely generated projective module. This module is $R^n$.